# Python Indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, indexing

I have generated this following code first to calculate the frequencies of each element in the IDs list:

```
    IDs =['fht142', 'fht142','fht178']
    freqs = {}
    for each in IDs:
        freqs[each] = freqs.get(each, 0) + 1
        print (each,freqs[each])
    print (freqs)
```

so my freqs would look at this: {'fht178': 1, 'fht142': 2}

I just wonder how I could print out freqs as following:

```
   fht178 1
   fht142 2
```

many thx!!

Comment: Also note `freqs = collections.Counter(IDs)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can say:

```
for k, v in freqs.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data =  {'fht178': 1, 'fht142': 2}
for k,v in data.iteritems():
  print k,v

fht178 1
fht142 2
```